# What the optimize way to apply appsync subscription without using react-apollo to the react App?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync

I am doing a sample project with aws Appsync and ReactJs and my mutations are working fine. But I need a way to do the subscription part  without using react-apollo. As far as I know Appsync is built based on apollo. So I believe there should be a way to do it purely with Appsync, by passing apollo.

I need some suggestions from expertise. Thanks in advance,

I tried with apoollo. But I need to do with minimum dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Amplify client https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#amplify-graphql-client

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with apoollo. But I need to do with minimum dependencies.

You will always need a dependency since you will need a GraphQL client.

Here are some GraphQL clients that supports subscription aside from Apollo:

- [Relay](https://relay.dev/docs/en/subscriptions)
- [Amplify API](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api)

Since subscriptions are using web sockets under the hood, you can make use of [Redux Saga's event channel](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#eventchannelsubscribe-buffer).

Comment: Why is it important to use `<ApolloProvider>` ? My concern was find another way to do it without passing the client inside the Apollo Provider. Please note that I'm new to Appsync

Comment: It provides the `client` (graphql client). See [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for more info.